# Bootstrap change $grid-gutter-width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstraps grid system and I need about a **`2px` space between each column**. I've tried Column-Gap but nothing.

Could anyone help?

Code HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3" id="one">
<h3>Pink</h3>

</div>
<div class="col-md-3" id="two">
<h3>Purple</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" id="three">
<h3>Green</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" id="four">
<h3>Orange</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row2">
<div class="col-md-3" >
<h3>Things that are Pink</h3>
<p>Pigs</p>
<p>Barbie</p>
<p>Some Skins</p>
<p>Ham</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" >
<h3>Things that are Purple</h3>
<p>Prince</p>
<p>Goths</p>
<p>Paint</p>
<p>Berries</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" >
<h3>Things that are Green</h3>
<p>Grass</p>
<p>Peas</p>
<p>Leafs</p>
<p>Apple</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" >
<h3>Things that are Orange</h3>
<p>Orange</p>
<p>Ice-Lolly</p>
<p>Essex</p>
<p>Carrots</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code: CSS

```
body {
font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;

}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.jumbotron {
padding-top: 48px;
padding-bottom: 48px;
}

.jumbotron {
text-align: center;
}

.container {
text-align: center;
}

#one {
border: 5px solid pink;
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: pink;
color: white;
}

#two {
border: 5px solid purple;
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: purple;
color: white;
}

#three {
border: 5px solid green;
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: green;
color: white;
}

#four {
border: 5px solid orange;
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: orange;
color: white;
}

.row2 {
margin-top: 30px;
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Comment: your DOM structure doesn't match the bootstrap way. Each row **must** have a `12` cols.

Answer (score 8):

A quick guide to resizing Bootstrap’s gutter width

**Resizing Bootstrap's Gutter**

A simple method of changing Bootstrap's default gutter size.

HTML

```
<div class="gutter-2 row">
 <div class="col-md-6"></div>
 <div class="col-md-6"></div>
```

`

CSS

```
.gutter-2.row {
    margin-right: -1px;
    margin-left: -1px;
  }
  .gutter-2 > [class^="col-"], .gutter-2 > [class^=" col-"] {
    padding-right: 1px;
    padding-left: 1px;
  }`
```

Comment: try to add a description if possible

Comment: providing a solution without using SASS. Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

to change the `gutter` you have two way:

1. change `@grid-gutter-width` in [`variables.less:327`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/less/variables.less#L327), but then you will need to compile the generated css yourself.
2. change `@grid-gutter-width` and download a new custom build at [Bootstrap#Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system)

Note that the customize section will be dropped in `twitter bootstrap 4`.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying but I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Bootstrap is highly customisable, you can change almost everything but you need to operate on a lower level because `bootstrap.css` is just an outcome of the raw files. If you don't know how to implement a build pipeline, may http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system suits better for you.

Comment: this more logical and right way for customization.