# Changing Bootstrap 4 gutters without Sass

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns, grid-layout

Is this possible?

I did find an answer on the following post:
[Bootstrap change $grid-gutter-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652337/bootstrap-change-grid-gutter-width)

...and then added this code to my CSS:

```
/* .row {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}

.row > [class^="col-"], .row > [class^=" col-"] {
   padding-right: 20px;
   padding-left: 20px;
 } */
```

But I then end up with a horizontal scrollbar on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gutter also applies to the container which creates the outermost (left & right) gutters...

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/tLhmBhDfS5)